# Codebuild: Finding the log stream name before the error log has been made

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am working an interface to help with deploying pipelines, and am trying to return the error logs when the codebuild fails. However, I need the logGroup and logStream parameters to use the function sendLogs provided by aws, and i cannot find a way to predict the logStream that will be created before it is made (it is produced when the build fails). Is there a way to find the log stream name that is created/used by codebuild when it makes a new error log within my logGroup?

Answer (score 0):

You can now define the CloudWatch log group name and stream prefix for build logs when creating/updating your CodeBuild build project. API reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_CreateProject.html#CodeBuild-CreateProject-request-logsConfig